# Are these two equation equal? $f(x)=\sin(4x)-\sin(3x)\cos(x)$ and $g(x)=\sin(x)\cos(3x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I have been trying to get these equations into a sum or difference of sin formula but since the first equation has the $-\sin(3x)\cos(x)$ in it, I keep getting hung up on the multiplication.  I did set the two equations equal to each other but I am not seeing how these two equations are equal.  The back of the book says they are.

$$\sin(4x)-\sin(3x)\cos(x)= \cos(3x)\sin(x)$$
$$-\sin(3x)\cos(x)-\cos(3x)\sin(x) = -\sin(4x)$$

At this point the sum of sin formula looks possible if I multiply by $-1$

$$\sin(3x)\cos(x)+\cos(3x)\sin(x)=\sin(4x)$$
$$\sin(a+b)=\sin(3x)\cos(x)+\cos(3x)\sin(x)$$

But, I really do not think the $\sin(4x) = \sin(a+b)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity in question is

$$\sin(a+b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) + \sin(b)\cos(a)$$

and so

$$\sin(3x)\cos(x) + \sin(x)\cos(3x) = \sin(3x + x) = \sin(4x) \\ \implies \sin(4x)-\sin(3x)\cos(x) = \sin(x)\cos(3x)$$

so yes, $f(x)=g(x)$.

Comment: Thanks, I was having a hard time making that connection.  It must be similar to saying the $sin(\frac{5\pi}{12})=sin(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{6})$